# Taskbar button/icon does not appear properly if it is set to combine

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, icons, taskbar

I am facing the issue in windows 7 taskbar button. When set Taskbar Button property to "Always combine" then my winform application (developed using VS 2010) buttons appeared with default icon.
But if I set Taskbar Buttons property to "Never combine" then it appears with correct icon which I have set for my exe application.

Any idea how can I resolve this issue.. it is suppose to come with icon on combine always settings.

Regards,
Subodh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a windows forms application in VS 2010. Added an icon (linked to ico file directly - not through resources) to the project properties (Resources -> Icon: -> Browse). The exe used the new icon.
When changing from 'Always combine' to 'Never combine', the same thing you described happened. 
I went back to the project and added the same ico file as an icon for the form. Rebuilt and the problem was gone.
It appears that when using 'Never combine', Windows 7 uses the form icon to display elements in the taskbar. While, when using 'Always combine', it uses the program's icon.